# Abbreviating code/functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I abbreviate a function (specifically a websocket) code in Javascript?

I have several files for each trading exchange that has different syntax's for running a websocket. From the one main file, how do I call any of these functions from different files using minified code?

Example:

`binance.js` (exchange 1)

```
var client = await loadKeys();
client.ws.trades([symbol], async trade => {
    console.log(trade);
});
```

`main.js`

```
const binance = require('../exchanges/binance.js');

(exchange).trade_socket("ETHBTC", async trade => {
    console.log(trade);
});
```

So basically, what I am trying to do is use the self defined keyword "trade_socket" to universally call any exchanges trade websocket.

I tried this in the binance.js function but it didnt work:

```
var temp = client.ws.trades;
return temp;
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Where and how is `exchange` defined? Where and how is `trade_socket` defined? Is this intended to be run inside a browser or maybe the Node.js runtime?

Comment: You can try `temp = client.ws.trades.bind(client.ws)`. This is because javascript has dynamic binding

Answer (score -1):

You must define an interop layer for each exchange's API which returns the same standard API that you define.

Suppose you have several third party libraries which expose different APIs.

```
const exchangeA = require('exchangeA');
const exchangeB = require('exchangeB');
const exchangeC = require('exchangeC');
const exchangeD = require('exchangeD');
return {
  exchangeA: {
    trade_socket: (sym, cb) => exchangeA.ws.keys(sym, cb)
  }
  exchangeB: {
    trade_socket: (sym, cb) => exchangeB.performTrade(sym).then(cb)
  }
  exchangeC: {
    trade_socket: (sym, cb) => exchangeC.setup().trade(sym, cb)
  }
  exchangeD: {
    trade_socket: (sym, cb) => exchangeD.goofyApi.withSymbol(sym).trade().then(cb)
  }
}
```

Now you can pick an arbitrary exchange and expect to be able to call the same methods.

```
import exchangeShims = require('./my-shims');
const exchange = exchangeShims['exchangeB'];
exchange.trade_socket("ETHBTC", async trade => {
    console.log(trade);
});
```

Comment: Not totally sure, but I think calling the method after minification is the focus of this question

Comment: I don't see any minification in the question

Comment: `...functions from different files using minified code?` <- See the second paragraph in the question